# Fresh install of Trellis by Roots on Mac & VituralBox is missing composer.json under /srv/www/example.com/current

Tags: wordpress, ansible, roots-sage

This is the error message I got when I first run `vagrant up` under the trellis directory:

```
TASK [wordpress-install : Install Dependencies with Composer] ******************
System info:
Ansible 2.9.0; Vagrant 2.2.6; Darwin
Trellis Head
---------------------------------------------------
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /srv/www/example.com/current
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section failed: [default] (item=example.com) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"key": "example.com", "value": {"admin_email": "admin@example.test", "cache": {"enabled": false}, "local_path": "../site", "multisite": {"enabled": false}, "site_hosts": [{"canonical": "example.test", "redirects": ["www.example.test"]}], "ssl": {"enabled": false, "provider": "self-signed"}}}, "stdout": "Composer could not find a composer.json file in /srv/www/example.com/current\nTo initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ \"Getting Started\" section\n", "stdout_lines": ["Composer could not find a composer.json file in /srv/www/example.com/current", "To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ \"Getting Started\" section"]}
```

How do I fix this? Where to find the right composer.json for Trellis, Bedrock, and Sage for local development on Mac?

Mac Catalina (10.15.2)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I finally figured it out. You gotta give Full Disk Access (Preference>Security & Privacy>Privacy) to /sbin/nfsd on MacOS Catalina.